# How to find code (eg functions) that is not referenced by any other code?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

Every time I come back to rust I am baffled by how the warnings for unused code work, they're transitive! Even if function `f` is called from function `g`, `f` will still be considered unused if `g` is unused.

I'm sure this is very useful behavior for some circumstances but I find myself missing warnings for unused code found in the linters for other programming languages. When searching I found [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/on-dead-code-warnings/31279) which perfectly describes my sentiment. To me warnings for dead code are important to identify work to do next and possible bugs, but the useful warnings are buried in a sea of spammy warnings of *transitively* unused code, not actually unused code.

Are there any configuration options or other tools I can use for identifying "real" unused code? Or am I looking at this in the wrong way?

I searched google trying to find previous relevant discussions or solutions and didn't find anything other than the [previously mentioned post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/on-dead-code-warnings/31279).

Comment: Not really an answer but developing the other way round with bunch of `todo!()`s in places not yet implemented avoids that problem alltogether, i.e. first write the code that uses a function, then write the function. Alternatively splitting into a library that exports a bunch of functionality and a binary that eventually uses it also cirumvents the problem, `pub fn` are never unused.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @cafce25! I definitely use `todo!` quite a bit but I guess I "go from both directions" since I still wind up with functions that haven't been "hooked up" to anything yet. Making everything `pub` seems similar to allowing dead code everywhere. I do want warnings on unused code, I just want to find the root cause.